# Should keystore password be same as PKCS12 certificate password?

Tags: java, keystore, keytool, pkcs#12

I am trying to import PKCS12 certificate using keytool in java. It works fine only when the keystore password is the same as certificate password. Is it mandatory to use the PKCS12 certificate password for keystore as well?

Comment: What error do you see when the keystore and certificate passwords do not match?

Comment: There's no explicit error thrown. The certificate gets installed but my application does not come up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [documentation of keytool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html#keytool_option_importkeystore) (only options relevant to this question are listed):

> **keytool -importkeystore** [**-srcstorepass** *srcstorepass*] [**-deststorepass** *deststorepass*] {**-srcalias** *srcalias* {**-destalias** *destalias*} [**-srckeypass** *srckeypass*]}
>   [**-destkeypass** *destkeypass*] ...
>
> Imports a single entry or all entries from a source keystore to a
>   destination keystore.
>
> When the **-srcalias** option is provided, the command imports the single
>   entry identified by the alias to the destination keystore.
>   [...] If the source entry is protected by a
>   password, then *srckeypass* is used to recover the entry. If *srckeypass*
>   is not provided, then the keytool command attempts to use *srcstorepass*
>   to recover the entry. If *srcstorepass* is either not provided or is
>   incorrect, then the user is prompted for a password. The destination
>   entry is protected with *destkeypass*. If *destkeypass* is not provided,
>   then the destination entry is protected with the source entry
>   password. **For example, most third-party tools require** *storepass* **and**
>   *keypass* **in a PKCS #12 keystore to be the same. In order to create a
>   PKCS #12 keystore for these tools, always specify a -destkeypass to be
>   the same as -deststorepass.**
>
> If the **-srcalias** option is not provided, then all entries in the source
>   keystore are imported into the destination keystore. [...] If the source entry
>   is protected by a password, then *srcstorepass* is used
>   to recover the entry. If *srcstorepass* is either not provided or is
>   incorrect, then the user is prompted for a password. [...] The destination entry is
>   protected with the source entry password.

So, whether it  is mandatory to use the PKCS12 certificate password for keystore as well depends on the application that will try to read the keystore.

Answer (score 3):

If you're relying on the Java system properties to inform JSSE about the keystore, there is no property for specifying a particular key alias or its password. In this circumstance you don't have any choice but to make the passwords the same.